# What is the canonical way to control the closing of goroutine if one goroutine is complete?

Tags: multithreading, go, channel, goroutine

I have a slice of struct that defines a task, each task is run in a goroutine, and I want all go goroutines to stop whenever the first one complete a task via the signal `task.signalComplete`

Currently I have the following.

```
for _, task := range taskList {
    go func(task *myTask, firstCompleteSignal chan<- bool) {
        for {
            select {
                // When the task completes, it emit signalComplete
                case <-task.signalComplete:
                    firstCompleteSignal<-true
                    return
            }
        }

    }(task, firstCompleteSignal)
}

for {
    select {
    case <-firstCompleteSignal:
        // manually stop all go thread
        return
    }
}
```

Is this canonical?

Or is there library to do this for me like sync.WaitGroup for waiting all goroutine to be done?

Comment: You might want to search for the term "goroutine" as this is what you are interested (and where you can find examples) and not threads.

Comment: @Volker Thanks for the advice, I did do a bit research, but most of the example I found ask for waiting of all goroutine to be finished, not wait until the first one to be finished. I edit my wording to be more precise in the terminology

Comment: @user3591466: how can you have a slice of goroutine? Are you looking for cancelation, with something like [`Context`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#Context)?

Comment: @JimB you are correct, slice of goroutine is confusing, I actually have a slice of task, and each task is run in a goroutine. I was looking for libraries that deal closing all task when the first task is complete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common idiom is to have a `Done` channel shared between the calling code and the goroutines.

Then each goroutine would check that channel via a `select` each time they 
send a new value to the calling code.

You can find a good example in Go's blog:

https://blog.golang.org/pipelines

(look for "Explicit Cancellation" there)

Later, they incorporated a `context` package to the standard library, and that is now the most "standard" way to manage cancellation of goroutines.

You can find a good example in the documentation for the package itself:

https://golang.org/pkg/context/#example_WithCancel